# SocketException Permission denied (connect failed)

Tags: spring-boot, socketexception

I have encountered the above exception when running our springboot web app in liberty server (on linux) to access another url with port 8081. As I am new to Spring and Java, can anyone help me to address the problem?

Below is my finding so far:

1) I can access the url (with different account) in linux command line.

2) I have checked with our linux support, it is not firewall or port issue.

3) I can access the url when running the web app in my local PC.

4) For debug, I try to access another url (which is pointing to the webservice in my local PC) from the server, it will work when the port is 9080, but fail if the port is 8082 (I could not run my local webservice with port 8081 as it has been used).

Comment: usually web servers are run with a user that has no permissions.  What user is running the webserver?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, it is run under user name wasadm

Answer (score 0):

after adding socket permission in the java policy file, it can work correctly now.